# How to create a layout for 480X800 android screen sizes?

Tags: android, optimization, android-studio, screen-density

So, i read the docs on how to support multiple screensizes. i have no problem for screen qualifiers greater than sw320 . but when i tried my emulator on devices <=320 like nexus S, the images overlaps with each other.

Nexus S has a screen size of (480 x 800) and it's density is 240dpi

so calculating using the formula given in the docs:

px=dp*(dpi/160)

dp= px/(dpi/160)

dp= 480/(240/160)

dp= 320

so using the qualifier < sw320 > should have worked yes? but it's not working in my situation. I tried changing the bitmaps to drawable-hdpi too but the emulator didn't use that drawable

Did i do something wrong?

Comment: Add your screenshot and xml layout, it will easy to help your problem. Maybe, problem when you design in xml layout.

Comment: you just Add first your screen shot and if overlapped image you can set programmatic code for setting that image using fetching device screen size.

Comment: `a screen size of (480 x 800) and it's density is 240dpi` Which is the perfect **hdpi** screen. `so using the qualifier < sw320 > should have worked yes?` **NO**. `Did i do something wrong?` **YES**. It seems you're confusing dps with dpis.

Comment: i found the solution. Thanks people

Comment: @WilliamAnputra How did you solve the issue? I am facing the same issue now.